# How to get attribute value? DomParser

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have method:

```
 private static void print(NodeList nodeList) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node t = nodeList.item(i);

        if (t.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println("node: " + t.getNodeName());
            System.out.println("values " + t.getTextContent());
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
        }



        if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
            print(t.getChildNodes());
        }
    }

}
```

It displays the contents of the xml document:

```
<Card>
        <Thema>people</Thema>
        <Type sent="true">advertising</Type>
        <Country>India</Country>
        <Year>1966</Year>
        <Authors><Author>Julia</Author></Authors>
        <Valuable>historical</Valuable>
    </Card>
```

but does not show the value of the attribute in the node "sent". How can I modify it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the method [getAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes()) to get the list of attributes of a node:

> A `NamedNodeMap` containing the attributes of this node (if it is an Element) or null otherwise.

Comment: when I try do this, I get "null pointer exception"

Comment: Check if you apply this method to a null node. Or if you try to loop to a null result of this call